# some APT packages are not showing up in Debian Buster after FGLRX install. how do I fix this?

Tags: apt, dependencies, proprietary-drivers, synaptic, fglrx

Hello fellow Debian Users,

I recently purchased a **Dell Optiplex 790**, Installed Debian 10.9 and put an **ATI Saphire card** in it. Needing drivers to fix screen discoloration upon display size change, I added the **FGLRX proprietary driver**. Now I needed to setup some applications like OBS studio and I can't seem to find them in **Synaptic**. I tried downloading the deb files manually to install but the **dependencies conflict with core packages**. I want to **get synaptic back to having full main Debian repository packages**. How do I do that?

output of Aptitude sources:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.9.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20210327-10:42]/ buster main 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.9.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20210327-10:42]/ buster main 

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports contrib main 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-backports contrib main 

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates contrib main 
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib 

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates contrib main 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib 

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: Where did you get your driver from? If it was from an Ubuntu, it was always likely to give future dependency problems in Debian.

Comment: no the package is from the "non-free" repository from Debian. I ended up changing it back to the main to try and fix the issue and nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main repository is missing in your sources.

You need to add at least

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list` (see [Example sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)) and reload the package index with

```
sudo apt update
```

in the terminal or choose "Reload Package Information" (<kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>) in synaptic.

Comment: Well that certainly helped thank you so much Freddy!